# How to call the method which has an only "long" type argument for using BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, remoteobject

I can't call the method which has an only "long" type argument for using Adobe BlazeDS?

Here is it.

[Flex]

```
var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject();
ro.destination = "objectService";
ro["getById"].send(3107);
```

[Java]

```
public class ObjectServiceImpl implements ObjectService {
    public ObjectDomain getById(long id) {
       ・・・
    }
}
```

so, this error was occured.

```
flex.messaging.MessageException: Cannot invoke method 'getById'. 3,107
arguments were sent but 1 were expected.
at flex.messaging.util.MethodMatcher.methodNotFound(MethodMatcher.java:387)
at flex.messaging.util.MethodMatcher.getMethod(MethodMatcher.java:172)
at
flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.invoke(JavaAdapter.java:417)
at
flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingService.java:183)
at
flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java:1400)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:1005)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a3ef066.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:572)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$49c0058b.serviceMessage(<generated>)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
at
flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$49c0058b.service(<generated>)
at
org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:101)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

[Environment]
・BlazeDS 4.0
・Spring BlazeDS Integration 1.0.3
・Spring 3.0.5
・Tomcat 5.0
・Java 5.0
・Flex 4.6

Please tell me any solutions..

Comment: What was the argument's value? Sure you were sending a serialized Number?

Comment: Please post also the FLex/AS3 sample code of the ws.call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
        //The way you defined the RemoteObject
        var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject();
        ro.destination = "objectService";

        //The id variable
        var id:Number = 3107;
        //The Operation to send over the RemoteBoject
        var getByIdOperation:Operation = new Operation();
        //Name of the method on the server side
        getByIdOperation.name = "getById";
        //The argument in this case the long 3107 ( var id:Number= 3107)
        getByIdOperation.arguments = [id];
        //The method to handle the result if needed
        getByIdOperation.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, getByIdHandler)
        //Send the operation through the RemoteObject(ro)
        ro.operations = [getByIdOperation];
        getByIdOperation.send();
```

java.lang.*Long* is represented as *Number* in ActionScript-3. Example method called when the remote call recieves the result

```
    private function getByIdHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        myObject = event.result as ObjectDomain;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was resolved! But why? The Operation instance have to declared explicitly and set to RemoteObject instance?

Comment: Your welcome! Im glad i could help :) No, as far as i know it doesn't have too. You can do as you did with _ro[method].send(arg1, arg2);_ I'm not completely sure why it doesnt work for you, because when i tried it it works fine. You can try putting 3107 in "" like _ro["getById"].send("3107");_

Comment: @Take remember to set the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem :)